# How to call method only after location data were received from CLLocaitonManager delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sequence, cllocationmanager

I have longitude and latitude of some shops in my city. After determine the distance between device/user location and shops, all data are show in the table. By default when app launches i need to call method which sort shops by distances and then reload tableview. Please suggest me how and where (sequence of methods) to call sorting method, because sometimes device/user location data is not yet received and table was sorted wrong.  Bad english, sorry

To determine location i'am using **CLLocationManagerDelegate:**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    myNewLocation = newLocation;
    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

Then (CCLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation: method in tableview:cellforIndexPath

Sorting method called in *viewDidLoad*:

```
- (NSArray*)getSortedArray:(NSArray*)shops byLocation:(CLLocation*)userLocation{
    NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [shops sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
        Shop *dict1 = (Shop*)obj1;
        Shop *dict2 = (Shop*)obj2;
        CLLocation *shopLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[[dict1 lat]doubleValue]
                                                                 longitude:[[dict1 lon]doubleValue]];
        CLLocation *shopLocation2 = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[[dict2 lat]doubleValue]
                                                                 longitude:[[dict2 lon]doubleValue]];
        CLLocationDistance key1 = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:shopLocation];
        CLLocationDistance key2 = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:shopLocation2];
        NSNumber *num1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:key1];
        NSNumber *num2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:key2];
        return [num1 compare:num2];
    }];
    return sortedArray;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not calling it before reloadData?

Comment: Yes, because I need to do some more sorting.
First the default I do sort by distance, and then on the user's choice, on button clicks. I hope you understand me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a block. Blocks can be used for callbacks, defining the code to be executed when a task completes.

Here is an example from the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

```
- (IBAction)fetchRemoteInformation:(id)sender {
[self showProgressIndicator];

XYZWebTask *task = ...

[task beginTaskWithCallbackBlock:^{
    [self hideProgressIndicator];
}];
}
```

This example calls a method to display the progress indicator, then creates the task and tells it to start. The callback block specifies the code to be executed once the task completes; in this case, it simply calls a method to hide the progress indicator.

In your case, the callback block would contain your code for sorting, which would wait for the location data to be received.